# Twitter Typeahead. Why is the .typeahead('val') returning the wrong value?

Tags: jquery, typeahead.js

I am using Twitter Typeahead and it is working well for me with the exception of one issue. When I select one of the suggestions from the presented list I want to capture and render the string used to create the suggestion list. I have done the following:

```
$search_input.bind('typeahead:select', function(ev, suggestion) {

    var query = $(this).typeahead('val');
    console.log('your query ' + query);
});
```

I would expect query to be the string I entered but it is instead the `display` option used to configure my typeahead instance.

How do I capture the original query string?

Comment: does suggestion not return what you are looking for?

Comment: suggestion is the record from the dataset Typeahead is configured with. I am after the sub-string I entered that was matched by suggestion.